# how to use autocomplete in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application with add friend feature, in that feature, user must fill their friend's username in the textbox. this is the html code:

```
<div content-for="title">
    <span>Add Friend</span>
</div>
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">User ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="add.email" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="User ID">
   </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="addfriends()">Add</button>
```

[the interface will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzStH.png)

and this is the js code:

```
// addfriend
    $scope.add = {};
    $scope.addfriends = function(){
        $scope.messages = {
            email      : $scope.add.email,
            userid     : $scope.datauser['data']['_id']
        };
          //event add friend
        socket.emit('addfriend',$scope.messages,function(callback){
            if(!callback['error']){
                $scope.datauser['data']['penddingrequest'].push(callback['data']);
                  //push pendding request to localstorage user
                localStorageService.remove('user');
                localStorageService.add('user', $scope.datauser);

                $scope.add['email'] = '';
                alert('Successfully added friend');
            }else{
                var msg = callback['error'];
                navigator.notification.alert(msg,'','Error Report','Ok');
            }
        });
    };
```

I want to change this feature little bit, I want to make this textbox showing some suggestion based on the input, like if user input 'a', the textbox will show all user id that start with 'a'. something like twitter's searchbox or instagram searchbox. these user ids is from database.
[example searchbox of web instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3kaA.png)

my question is how to change this textbox to be autocomplete but still work like before? thanks very much

Comment: i am also looking for the same.. did u get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

First is this one: You basically create Angular directive for your `input`.
http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/

Another way to do is to attach `onKeyUp` event to your `input`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">User ID</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="add.email" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="User ID" ng-keyup="searchFriends()">
  <div ng-model="searchFriendsResult" />
</div>
```

And then, in your `controller`, you create a `searchFriends` function that will:

1. Search your database
2. Display the result in the view.

Something like this (not a complete code):

```
$scope.searchFriends = function(value){
    // Make Ajax call
    var userRes = $resource('/user/:username', {username: '@username'});
    userRes.get({username:value})
        .$promise.then(function(users) {
            $scope.searchFriendsResult = users;
        });
};
```

Comment: I am not using ajax in this app, and my database is mongodb. can you help me again?

Comment: Well, autocomplete will need ajax and by that I mean, async JavaScript call, without round trip to server. If you don't use that, I assume you already have the data once the page is loaded? In that case, the first option should work. The sample preloaded the data on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bootstrap Typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" 
                    placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" 
                    uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" 
                    typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
                    typeahead-no-results="noResults" 
                    class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: how to use this in my case? that must get the value from mongodb, thanks

Comment: See the docs.. the `getLocation($viewValue)` function must bring your collection from somewhere (javascript array, $http or whatever you want)